# Is there a way to add an insurance element in the **price_data** Stripe checkout object?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am integrating **Stripe checkout** on my website and I want to add the **insurance fee** before calculating the total.
Is there a way to add an insurance element in the **price_data** object or something like that? Or is there another way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "insurance fee"? Is it a fee you compute on your end, and you want the Checkout Session amount to be: total minus insurance fee? You can't add a `price_data` with a negative amount, but you could add a [`discount`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=go#create_checkout_session-discounts) to your Checkout Session to reduce the total price.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my question, instead of writing add the insurance I put subtract.
The insurance is the charge that the customer must pay in addition to the total to reimburse in case of alteration/loss of products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a Checkout Session, you can set multiple prices inside `line_items`. For example here's how to set two `price_data` in Node.js

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  mode: "payment", 
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  line_items: [
    // First price
    {
      price_data: {
        unit_amount: 1000,
        currency: "usd",
        product_data: { name: "something" }
      },
      quantity: 1,
    }, 
    // Second price
    {
      price_data: {
        unit_amount: 1000,
        currency: "usd",
        product_data: { name: "something else" }
      },
      quantity: 1,
    }
  ],
});
```

Comment: Yes, it doas the work for me, I didn't know that we can make several price_data in the same line_items (as I'm new to Stripe ^^" ).
Although I wish Stripe had added an insurance element in the price_data object, just like shipping info ...